# Eval code doesn't work

Tags: php, eval

I try to make e eval code, but something went wrong, and i cannot find the error.

I've got this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/classes/databasehandler.php(57) : eval()'d code on line 1

Here is the code:

```
eval("$s->bind_param('".$binds."', ".$values.");");

$BINDS ARE: ss
$VALUES ARE: 'testing','hej123'
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of the bind_param() method ?

Comment: you don't need eval() to call bind_param() dynamically - you can improvize and use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead, which is a much cleaner, reliable and faster way to accomplish this

Comment: Aren't you expanding $s as well?

Comment: It's mysqli's bind_param(), isn't it? http://docs.php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes are parsed by PHP, so `eval("$s->bind_param...");` is equal to `eval($s."->bind_param...');`. Replace double with single quotes and your ***EVIL*** code will work.

If you're sure your values are delimited by comma's why not create the array yourself?

```
$values = explode(',',preg_replace('/[\'"]/g','',$values));
```

Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `eval()` for this? It can be achieved as follows:

```
$binds = 'si';
$values = array('a string', 4609);
$args = array($binds) + $values;
call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), $args);
```

The code above is faster (doesn't invoke a new execution context), more secure (variables are passed directly, no assumptions on escaping).

Comment: `bind_param` does not support an array as the second parameter.

Comment: @xdazz I'm afraid I didn't bother looking that up, I just translated his code. He didn't specify what library it is - it could have been custom as far as I know.

Comment: When using call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), array($binds, array($values))); i've got: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/classes/databasehandler.php on line 60

Comment: Well, here we're assuming since I don't even know if you're talking about mysqli or something else. I'll rewrite the code in a way I think it should work.

Comment: Doesnt work either. There is no arrays in the bind. I don't know why you insert arrays. When i remove array($binds) i've got an error again.

Comment: It is MySQLI i am trying to do.

Comment: @JesperKampmannMadsen Then please do us all a favor and show us the code you want to run, not what you're trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Eval, and certainly not for something trivial as binding  a parameter to a query!

Comment: My currently code is this, maybe you can re-write it better than me:

Comment: I fully agree with the sentiment, but this kind of thing needs to be posted as a comment, not an answer, unless you can provide a constructive alternative as well.